# Why does "hg status" show changed files when "hg diff -g" doesn't? (One parent)

Tags: mercurial

I have a repository where:

```
> hg st
```

shows that my working directory has some uncommitted changes, while

```
> hg diff


> hg diff -g


> hg diff --git
```

display nothing.

I read here: [4.10. hg status shows changed files but hg diff doesn't!](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.hg_status_shows_changed_files_but_hg_diff_doesn.27t.21) the following:

> hg status reports when file contents or flags have changed relative to either parent. hg diff only reports changed contents relative to the first parent. You can see flag information with the --git option to hg diff and deltas relative to the other parent with -r.

However, if I run `hg parents` it shows only one parent (the tip). As I mention above, I have also tried `hg diff --git`  and it still displays nothing.

Note:

- The above is on **Mercurial version 2.0.1**
- `hg status` only shows `M` next to a regular file.
- `hg diff` and `hg diff -g` print nothing
- The filesystem is NFS.
- `hg parents` prints only one parent

Comment: What is the output of hg status?

Comment: have you tried running `hg diff --git` like said in the documentation you posted ?

Comment: hg status shows more than just uncommitted changes, it shows changed files, attributes, existence of files that are not tracked by Mercurial etc. hg diff will show changed contents.

Comment: @krtek Question is, if does make a difference, *why* does it make difference?

Comment: Make sure to note the hg version: it's still evolving a good bit in semantics.

Comment: @pyfunc, when you said that `hg status` checks also attributes, and things that `hg diff` does not show, is there a way to check what is exactly that has changed when `hg st` shows an `M` next to the file?.

Comment: I have same symptoms: after cloning the repository with Windows hg on a samba network share, on Linux side `hg status` shows modified files while `hg diff --git` shows nothing. File permissions are the same. One parent, freshly updated directory.

Comment: I get this a lot, and I've started running `hg debugrebuilddirstate` which will re-scan and get rid of any fake "m" flags...

Comment: You should promote 'hg debugrebuilddirstate' to an answer, it fixed my problem when nothing else did!

Comment: @ChrisJefferson I think you need to @ Rob to alert him.

Comment: @Rob you're comment is the answer.

Answer (score 22):

Some excerpts from [Mercurial in daily use (Mercurial: the definitive guide)](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html) (copying here because there seems to be no way to give a convinient link to the end of the page):

> The default output of the `hg diff` command is **backwards compatible** with the regular `diff` command, but this has some drawbacks.
>
> The output of hg diff above obscures the fact that we **simply renamed a file**. The hg diff command accepts an option, `--git` or `-g`, to use a newer diff format that displays such information in a more readable form.
>
> This option also helps with a case that can otherwise be confusing: a file that appears to be modified according to `hg status`, but for which `hg diff` prints nothing. This situation can arise if we change the **file's execute permissions**.
>
> The normal diff command pays no attention to file permissions, which is why `hg diff` prints nothing by default. If we supply it with the `-g` option, it tells us what really happened.

To summarize, `hg diff` command misses several kinds of information on changes: attributes, permissions, file names, etc. These changes may exist even if you have a single parent. And `hg status` correctly takes into account all changes. To see what has happened, use `hg diff -g`. It's the answer to the question 'what happens'.

Seems like backwards compatibility is the 'why'. I'm not sure, but I suppose that the 'normal diff' is some widespread or built-in Unix/Linux tool (judging from the fact that both hg and git come from that world).

Comment: I just run into this error again. `hg diff` and `hg diff -g` print nothing. `hg st` show a file as modified (`M` next to it).

Comment: @intrpc Does `hg parents` print only one parent? If it prints 2, you have merged and the file might have been modified in both branches, but it is equal upon merging. Or you may simply have changes relative to the scond parent, while `diff` works only relative to the first one.

Comment: `parents` prints only one parent. I also upgraded to the latest Hg version (and updated the OP accordingly).

Comment: After confirming none of the files were modified using `hg diff -g` and `hg diff -a`, an `hg revert` reset the status for the files.This was on OS X, the project directory was copied over from a network share

Comment: Changed execute permissions get me every time

Comment: This does not answer the question - the problem is that (on Linux) `hg diff -g` shows nothing where `hg status` shows modified files and where there is no difference in (traditional unix) file permissions. One parent, freshly updated directory.

Comment: @PavelGatilov The guide referenced is very helpful for status and diff as well as other basic usage, I wish I'd found it sooner.

Answer (score 10):

In these situations (it happens a lot to my team), I find that this command will fix about anything:

```
hg debugrebuilddirstate
```

or

```
hg debugrebuilddirstate -r tip
```

It's lightly documented in the [help documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/debugrebuilddirstate), but basically I believe it clears out the "dirstate" file which caches information about working-directory files.  The next time you `hg stat` it will refresh it from scratch.

One caveat: if you've *added* or *removed* files, that information will be lost when the `dirstate` is rebuilt.

Comment: When a WSL1 DrvFS remounted with different `fmask` and per-file metadata for UNIX permission bits are then enabled for individual tracked files, the state can go wrong. `hg debugrebuilddirstate` fixes it.

Answer (score 5):

If you have `ignorews` or `ignoreblanklines` set in `.hgrc` then `hg status` will show it as changed but `hg diff` won't (assuming the changes are only whitespace of course).

Comment: @intrpc Have you checked this?

Comment: Yes.  For mercurial 1.8 installed via homebrew on OS 10.6.  `hg diff` even has return status 0.

Comment: I'm sorry, Ivan, I didn't mean you haven't. I have asked @intrpc (the OP) if he had checked this situation. :)

Answer (score 4):

I just deleted the files that showed up as modified (make a backup if needed) which caused all the files to show up with an ! next to it when I ran

```
hg st
```

After that I ran the following command to revert the files (which were already checked in):

```
hg revert --all --no-backup
```

and that fixed the problem

Comment: This worked for me and is a lot easier than cloning the whole repo again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case something was broken with hg. (same permissions and hg diff -g shows nothing).
I fixed issue with next way:

1. I cloned repository again in separate folder
2. I removed everything from this folder except .hg
3. I moved from old (broken) place everything except .hg to new place

So after this step i have repository which cloned with current version of mercurial + exactly same files.

After this steps i received same (empty) results for commands: `hg st` and `hg diff -g`

Comment: In fact, the suggestion by [RPM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/327386/rpm) works already - deleting the files in question and reverting the changes works, no need for a new clone.